# Multiplicities of roots of a smooth family of polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

Let $p_x \left( z \right)$ be a smooth family of complex polynomials in $z$, smoothly parametrized by $x$ in a connected open subset $U \subseteq \mathbb R^n$. Suppose that the roots of $p_x$ do not depend on $x$. Is it true that the multiplicities of the roots are also constant? In other words, can I always write $p_x \left( z \right) = a\left(x\right)\sum_\mu \left(z-\mu\right)^{M_\mu}$, where $a$ is a smooth nowhere zero function on $U$, the sum is over the roots of $p_x$, and $M_\mu$ is the multiplicity of $\mu$?

Suppose that the answer to the above question is "yes". Can I say the same if the coefficients of $p_x$ are complex square matrices?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. The set of polynomials with a fixed set of roots (possibly of different multiplicities) is finite, so they're disconnected from each other, meaning no continuous (we don't need to assume smooth) family of polynomials can jump from any one of them to any other.

For your second question, it's certainly not true that polynomials with matrix coefficients have unique factorizations or finitely many roots, so I don't know what you mean by "multiplicities" here.